# Remove Duplicate Text in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the help of some people on this website I managed to create a hashtag counter here - https://codepen.io/timothycdavis17/pen/ZJeVBj.

Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<section class="section-textarea bg-primary">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="well textarea-well clearfix">
          <textarea rows="16" class="form-control"></textarea>

          <div class="buttons">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-primary btn-lg 
          count-button">Count</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-danger btn-lg 
          reset-button">Reset</button>

          </div>

      </div>

          <div class="remaining-counter">Hashtags Counted:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
          class="well text-well">0</span></div>


  </div>

 </div>

 </div>

 </div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #0275D8;
}

.textarea-well {
   color: #000;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 10% auto;
}

textarea {

  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.text-well {
  background: lightblue;
 }

.count-button {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.remaining-counter {
    font-size: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".count-button").click(function() {
  var text = $("textarea").val();
  var count = (text.match(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d A-Z\D][\w-]*)/g) || []).length;
  $('.text-well').html(count);

  var seen = {};
  $('textarea').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt])
      $(this).remove();
  else
      seen[txt] = true;
  });

}).trigger('click');


$(".reset-button").click(function() {
$("textarea").val(' ');
$('.text-well').html(0);
}).trigger('click');
```

After it was made I was asked whether it would be possible to not count any duplicate hashtags that are entered into the textarea and maybe error underline theme with a red squiggly line.

I've had a look around this website for answers but couldn't seem to find one that worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a temp array to filter out the duplicates.

```
// save the matches instead of immediately counting
var tags = text.match(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d A-Z\D][\w-]*)/g) || [];
// init empty array for holding unique matches
var uTags = [];
// loop through matches
$.each(tags, function(index, value){
  // if match is not in holding array array, add it to holding array
  if(uTags.indexOf(value) == -1) uTags.push(value);
});
// get count from holding array which will only have one copy of each match
var count = uTags.length;
```

[Here is a fork of your codepen with the above code.](https://codepen.io/amflare/pen/RZpmMM?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks very much, is there a way to style the duplicate text to show the user it's a duplicate?

Comment: Sure, add an else block to the if statement and add the code you want to run on duplicate-found

Comment: I've tried to add an else statement, but not entirely sure what I'm doing to be  honest. I've updated my codepen

Comment: This is starting to get outside the scope of the original question. However, I recommend pushing dups to a dupArray, then outputting the content of that array somewhere around the counter. You won't be able to style the actual hashtag inside the textarea.